# kafka AdminClient get kafka version

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to get the version of kafka cluster programmatically? Such as, using 
`AdminClient` API.

I want to identify the version of kafka cluster in a consumer/producer app.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment there is no way to retrieve the Kafka version brokers are running.

There is a KIP in progress to add that feature to the AdminClient: [KIP-483: Add Broker Version API in Admin Client](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-483%3A++Add+Broker+Version+API+in+Admin+Client) so that may be availabble in a future version.

In the meantime, there are a few workarounds you can try:

- Use [`describeConfigs()`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConfigs-java.util.Collection-) to find the `inter.broker.protocol.version` config of the brokers. If that returns `2.2-IV1`, it means the broker is running *at least* 2.2.
- Check the ApiVersions response. Upon starting clients send an ApiVersions request and the response is written in the logs (at the INFO level). Or manually send an [ApiVersions](http://kafka.apache.org/protocol#The_Messages_ApiVersions), it's pretty easy to craft such a request as it's an empty body. Then you can identify the broker version using https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+APIs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AppInfoParser.getVersion();` in your consumer/producer code.

Comment: this is the version of the kafka client, not of the kafka broker